# Dining Philosophers Problem in Clojure

Tags: asynchronous, clojure, dining-philosophers

I have implemented the Dining Philosophers Problem in Clojure with refs, trying to emphasize readability. Please point out if parts of it are inefficient, not idiomatic, or improvable in any way. [Full code on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/biellls/e81e3d09ed48b32acefc).

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;     DINING     ;;
;;  PHILOSOPHERS  ;;
;;     PROBLEM    ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(ns concurrency.dining-philosophers
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [clojure.core.async :refer [go chan >!! <!!]]))

(def n-philosophers 5)
(def max-eating-time 3000)
(def max-thinking-time 2000)
(def retry-time 5)
(def forks (for [_ (range 0 n-philosophers)]
             (ref false)))

;; We use a core async channel to implement a logger that writes
;;  to the terminal. It will run on the main thread
(def logger-chan (chan))

(defn log [& xs]
  (>!! logger-chan (apply str xs)))

(defn logger [channel]
  (println "Ready to log...")
  (while true
    (let [msg (<!! channel)]
      (println msg))))

;; The philosopher function contains the main logic of the application
(declare get-forks eat think wait-retry-time)
(defn philosopher
  "Given a philosopher's location n at the table, tries to pick up both
    forks simultaneously and eat. When he is finished eating he thinks
    for a while. If he cannot pick up both forks, he retries after a while.
   This function runs in a thread"
  [n]
  (log "Philosopher " n " just sat down")
  (while true
    (if (get-forks n)
      (do (log "Philosopher " n " picked up forks")
          (eat n)
          (think n))
      (wait-retry-time))))

(declare get-fork left-fork right-fork release-fork)
(defn get-forks
  "We try to get the left fork first, and then the right fork. If we succeed
    in getting the left fork but not the right, we drop the left fork.
   Returns true if we succeed in getting both forks and false otherwise."
  [n]
  (dosync
   (if (get-fork (left-fork n))
     (if (get-fork (right-fork n))
       true
       (release-fork (left-fork n)))
     false)))

(defn get-fork [fork]
  (if @fork
    nil
    (ref-set fork true)))

(defn left-fork [n]
  (nth forks (mod (dec n) n-philosophers)))

(defn right-fork [n]
  (nth forks n))

(defn release-fork [fork]
  (ref-set fork false))

(declare release-forks)
(defn eat [n]
  (log "Philosopher " n " is dining")
  (Thread/sleep (rand-int max-eating-time))
  (release-forks n)
  (log "Philosopher " n " dropped forks"))

(defn release-forks [n]
  (dosync
    (release-fork (left-fork n))
    (release-fork (right-fork n))))

(defn think [n]
  (log "Philosopher " n " is thinking")
  (Thread/sleep (rand-int max-thinking-time)))

(defn wait-retry-time []
  (Thread/sleep retry-time))

(defn -main []
  (println "Starting main")
  (dotimes [i n-philosophers]
    (.start (Thread. #(philosopher i))))
  (logger logger-chan))
(-main)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Idiosyncrasies

#### `declare`ing your `fn`s

It's pretty unusual to `declare` all of your functions before defining them.

It appears that you did it so that you could define your functions in the order you thought
most appropriate. That's common for newcomers, and it's certainly something many people are
used to. To be clear, there's *nothing* wrong with wanting that.

However, most clojure programs work within this constraint and just define things in the
order they are needed. After a while you become accustomed to seeing things in that order,
and you start to look at the bottom of the file for the program overview. This has the
minor benefit of calling out the places where circular references are actually needed.

#### Manually calling `-main`

This is a toy program, so calling `-main` in your namespace probably does what you want 100%
of the time. However, in a real codebase, doing that can pretty much make your namespace
unusable for other namespaces. If you're using `lein` you can call:

```
lein run -m concurrency.dining-philosophers
```

If you're running raw clojure use:

```
java -cp "clojure.jar:$OTHER_JAR_PATHS" clojure.main -m concurrency.dining-philosophers
```

### Program Structure

#### Decouple Philosophers

Your philosophers are aware of a lot of implementation details. Really all they care
about is their name, their left fork, and their right fork. You transmit all of that information
in a single number, which is convenient, but it means you have to be concerned with how
forks are retrieved in the `philosopher` code as opposed to just using the forks you're assigned.

The consequence of this is it binds your functions together in an undesirable way.

#### Leverage Sequences

Your solution uses a lot of indices and math to manipulate those indices. It could be made
dramatically simpler by manipulating sequences instead. (Hint: Use the above advice and the
`partition` function.)

#### Microfunctions

This is a really common thing for newcomers to clojure, myself included.

When I did a lot of Java, I tended to like very small functions, and I would create arbitrary
functions (e.g. `get-fork`, `release-fork` and `wait-retry-time`) for no other reason than to cut
down on my line count. After working with clojure for a while, function length became less important
than overall comprehensibility. So what I try and do now is look for fundamental *concepts* in my
program as opposed to places where I can inject a random function.

For example, for this problem, I see `get-forks`, `release-forks`, `eat`, and `think` as primitives.
They are things that are *inherent* to the problem. You may or may not name them, but they are definitely
there.

You never really want to get a single fork at one time, so `get-fork` seems too small to be a standalone
concept. The same for `release-fork`. `wait-retry-time` is just a pseudonym for `(Thread/sleep retry-time)`. The latter is going
to be more obvious to any newcomer to the codebase.

### General Comments

#### Use of core.async

Just to let you know, since you pulled in core.async, it's possible to do a lot of the
mechanics around starting/stopping threads with core.async. This has a couple of advantages:

- Removes the need to use Java constructs like `Thread/sleep`, `.start`, `.wait`. (As far as I know, this is really just an aesthetic advantage)
- Allows you to easily interact with processes (i.e. start them and stop them) (Another potential option here is [Java's Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html)
  infrastructure.)

So it's not a massive gain, but the option is there if you choose.

#### No cleanup mechanism

While we're on the topic of interacting with the processes, the current structure doesn't
leave any hooks for cleaning up your threads. This works fine for a toy program where you'll
let it run then <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd>, but any real-world system will need to handle that
cleanly. So it might be nice for you to use the opportunity to think about how to structure the
program so you can clean up on demand.

#### Unbuffered `logger-chan`

Since your `logger-chan` is an unbuffered `chan` you've introduced synchrony around your logging
when you probably want some asynchrony there. I can't see any harm in setting a buffer of ~100 or
~1000 on that channel. It'll almost certainly be way ahead of its workload, and in the event it gets
behind, it'll still give some backpressure so you won't lose any events.

### Closing Thoughts

I really like that you chose clojure's STM system for this problem. It's not often used, but by
far the best fit. Also, despite my nitpicking, the big picture flow of `philosopher` is straightforward
in the best kind of way.

Please let me know if you have any questions about my comments. I'm more than happy to give further feedback!

## Edit in response to OPs comments

### go-block lockup

You only get lock up if you occupy the thread (e.g. with `Thread/sleep`, or by doing IO or doing a CPU-intensive process). If you "park" it with `(<! (a/timeout msecs))` it doesn't block the state machine.

### core.async vs future

I was referring to the `thread` macro. I don't think there's any substantial benefit to core.async over the futures with and `Executor`. I actually did a version with `ExecutorService` and `Future`, and it has the same feature set. FWIW I think it's also more concise than the version I did with core.async.

However, it is very beneficial to use one of those two over `Thread/start` and `Thread/wait`. Those are pretty rudimentary constructs. And they suck for most use cases.

### Function Size

You pose a really good point regarding `get-fork`. You do indeed want to eliminate repetition where possible (though not at the expense of simplicity). I would agree that in the current implementation, `get-fork` needs to be its own function. However, I don't think getting a single fork is necessary for a solution to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I appreciate your feedback. I have some questions though. With core async are you referring to the "thread" function/macro? I think go wouldn't be appropriate since there is a lot of waiting in the program. And since I wouldn't be using the channels that thread returns, is there any advantage in using it vs using future.

Comment: Also, I get what you are dying about micro functions, but get-fork is not a one-liner and eliminating it would create quite a bit of repetition in the code. Aren't we supposed to eliminate repetition when possible? And if get-fork should be a function, then wouldn't release-fork also be one, even if it's only for consistency. I do agree with wait-retry-time though, it shouldn't be a separate function.

Comment: @user3146897 see my edits. Please let me know if you have any more questions!